# Import xaml file into usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a xaml file, named

> appbar.cabinet.files.xaml

and contains the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="appbar_cabinet_files" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
    <Path Width="42" Height="38" Canvas.Left="17" Canvas.Top="19" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 19,38L 19,22L 24,22L 24,20L 29,20L 29,19L 46.75,19L 57,29.25L 57,38L 59,38L 59,57L 58.5833,57L 17.4167,57L 17,57L 17,38L 19,38 Z M 24,38L 24,25L 22,25L 22,38L 24,38 Z M 27,23L 27,38L 29,38L 29,23L 27,23 Z M 43,46L 43,49L 33,49L 33,46L 43,46 Z M 54,38L 54,33L 43,33L 43,22L 32,22L 32,38L 54,38 Z M 46,22.75L 46,30L 53.25,30L 46,22.75 Z M 21,42L 21,53L 55,53L 55,42L 21,42 Z " />
</Canvas>
```

Now i want to import and use this in my usercontrol. On my usercontrol i have a button and this canvas i want to place inside content property on button. How can i do that?

Or should I rewrite to resource dictionary and import in app.xaml

Comment: `I want to import and use this in my usercontrol.` How do you want to use it? Do you want to display this text in your usercontrol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go

```
string myXamlFilePath = "appbar.cabinet.files.xaml";
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(myXamlFilePath);
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
Canvas loadedCanvas = (Canvas)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
myButton.Content = loadedCanvas;
```

more info on same here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590398